# Complexity of All-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, satisfiability

All-SAT is the problem of enumerating all satisfying assignments of a boolean formula.

All-SAT is different from #SAT, where it suffices to find the number of satisfying assignments without enumerating them.

Is the computational complexity of All-SAT known, or is this an open problem?

In [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/enumerate-all-solutions-of-a-sat-problem) CS Theory question, some solvers for All-SAT are discussed, but the papers do not seem to give complexity results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can naively compute ALL-SAT in $2^npoly(n,m)$ time, where $n$ is the number of variables and $m$ is the number of clauses. You clearly need $\Omega(2^n)$ time in the worst case just to write down the assignments (in the case of a tautology). If the strong exponential time hypothesis (SETH) holds, then this is not much harder than SAT itself, so under SETH the complexity of SAT, ALL-SAT, #SAT is the same (up to polynomial factors).

Moreover, without SETH you can claim that given access to a $\#SAT$ oracle, you can output all satisfying assignments in time $k(\varphi)poly(n,m)$ where $k(\varphi)$ is the number of satisfying assignments for $\varphi$ (just see if the number of satisfying assignments changes when substituting $1$ or $0$ to some variable $x_i$). This also shows that in some sense ALL-SAT is not much harder than $\#SAT$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: So this would mean that All-SAT $\in$ #P?

Comment: Well $\#P$ contains objects of a different type, so I wouldn't say that. You could treat the output of ALL-SAT as a natural number (encode the list of satisfying assignments) and then ask if this function can be described as the counter of some NP-machine. The membership to $\#P$ now might depend on the details of the encoding, but I don't suspect there is anything too deep here. My point was that they admit to the same lower bounds, and if you had a SAT or $\#SAT$ oracle you would obtain a near optimal solution for ALL-SAT.